# Application start after call ended

Tags: android, android-service

I am running my application in background for getting location at every 1 hour. and i also put code for read phone state like below:

```
public class IncomingCallInterceptor extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String msg = "Phone state changed to " + state;

        if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {
            String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            msg += ". Incoming number is " + incomingNumber;


            // TODO This would be a good place to "Do something when the phone rings" ;-)
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state)){
            Intent i = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                            context.getPackageName());
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }

    }
}
```

its works fine when my application is running and any phone calls come. and after phone call ended it goes back to my application. but main problem is when my application not running and any phone call come and after call ended, my application start automatically. i think reason is i am running my application in background thats why its start automatically. but its necessary to run in background. so what is the solution for stop my application automatically start after call ended when application is not running actually.??

Comment: explain why you down voted my question...

Comment: don't you want to receive the broadcasat when the application is not running?

Comment: my application is running in background already..

Comment: but you wrote that "ut main problem is when my application not running ...

Comment: not running means not in use..

Comment: Why are u starting intent in broadcast receiver??? If your app is opened and phone call comes, then after call ends the app will launch  automatically. There is no need of using intent for this.

Comment: Stop listening to phone state.

Answer (score 0):

your application again get called after Phonecall ended because  TelephonyManager will always listen the call state of a phone and when call ended it goes to IDLE state ..after some time it again calls the same Idle state so your APP just opens..try to use Boolean or something

```
boolean currentState=false;

then in OFFHOOK make it true and when first time goes in a idle state make it ture
```

and in IDLE STATE

```
 if(currentState) 
   {
  //open APP
    currentState=false;
   }
```